# Difference how to access the promise

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a difference between

```
var source1 = Rx.Observable.of(42);
const oneSubscription = source1.subscribe({
     next: x => console.log(x)
});
oneSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

and

```
var source2 = Rx.Observable.of(42);
source2.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

I thought that to create a promise you have to subscribe for it first.

But in case of `source2` the thing is just working without subscribing.

May be someone ca explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `forEach` internally subscribes as well.

```
/**
*  Subscribes an o to the observable sequence.
*  @param {Mixed} [oOrOnNext] The object that is to receive notifications or an action to invoke for each element in the observable sequence.
*  @param {Function} [onError] Action to invoke upon exceptional termination of the observable sequence.
*  @param {Function} [onCompleted] Action to invoke upon graceful termination of the observable sequence.
*  @returns {Diposable} A disposable handling the subscriptions and unsubscriptions.
*/
forEach(observer: IObserver<T>): IDisposable;
```

Comment: how would you access `next`, `error`, `complete` inside the `forEach`?

Comment: You can add more functions, like in `subscribe`, see http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/subscribe.html

Comment: @sreginogemoh Did this answer help you?